# Run Xcode ui tests on physical device with test code in pods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing, xcode7.3

We have created a test suite swift code which we wanted to reuse in different projects.

Our plan was as follows:

We create a pod where we put different helpers and base classes, so then this pod is used in different projects. We got no problem to get it up and running on iOS simulator but faced an issue on physical device. In order to keep it simple here's small list of steps to reproduce the issue. We take an example of existing pod of https://github.com/joemasilotti/JAMTestHelper as we got exactly same error here.

1. I create sample application with UI tests
2. Run `Cmd + U` got success
3. Add `Podfile` with the following content:

> ```
> target 'TestProjectUITests', :exclusive => true do
>     platform :ios, '9.0'
>     use_frameworks!
>     pod "JAMTestHelper"
> end
> ```

4. Run `pod install` (I use `0.39.0` version)
5. Run `Cmd + U` got error: XCTest' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

After google search figured the solution is setting enable bit code to NO: http://take.ms/TzN8I

6. Run `Cmd + U` got green build but tests always fail.

Full log is as follows:

```
2016-06-13 22:10:06.682 XCTRunner[20405:6816312] Running tests...
2016-06-13 22:10:06.749 XCTRunner[20405:6816312] The bundle “TestProjectUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
2016-06-13 22:10:06.749 XCTRunner[20405:6816312] (dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BE65B3E-8962-40CB-A6E7-D9F1ADE1D743/TestProjectUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/TestProjectUITests.xctest/TestProjectUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/JAMTestHelper.framework/JAMTestHelper
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6BE65B3E-8962-40CB-A6E7-D9F1ADE1D743/TestProjectUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/TestProjectUITests.xctest/TestProjectUITests
  Reason: image not found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which Xcode version you are using ? JAMTestHelper Requires Xcode 7.2 minimum